# Как в git откатиться на нужную версию и это состояние установить на вершину?

Tags: git, github

В ветке было много слияний, и git revert -m 1 tag..head в определенном моменте падает и continue ничего не хочет, хотел пойти другим способом вернул состояние на тег, сделал новую ветку и потом ее хотел смержить в ту которую хочу вернуть, но выдает already up to date, потому что он потомок родителя, а в родителе есть такое состояние, как я понимаю. Но как мне сделать новый коммит с прошлым состоянием?

Comment: если Вы получаете "already up to date", значит этот коммит уже есть в master. И вкомпитить повторно нет смысла. Возможно, просто сделать `git reset --hard нужный_коммит` и вперед?

Comment: Для тяжелых случаев есть `git reflog`, может вы не знаете. `хотел пойти другим способом` - вы все правильно сделали. `а в родителе есть такое состояние, как я понимаю` - правильно понимаете. Вы что хотите? Удалить какие-то коммиты? Тогда есть rebase, сделайте новую экспериментальную ветку, где попробуйте заребейзить. Вот нашел ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084013/how-do-you-revert-a-faulty-git-merge-commit), похож на ваш случай.